# How to initialize a combo box with true and false values using thymeleaf?

Tags: html, web-applications, thymeleaf

I have a combo box in my html page. I am using thymeleaf as the UI template framework. I am stuck at a place where I am not sure how to initialize the combo box which has options true and false. the code I have tried is as below:

```
                            <div class="input">
                                <select data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ComboBox" id="active"
                                    name="active">
                                    <option th:if="${user.active == true}" selected="selected">true</option>
                                    <option th:if="${user.active == false}" selected="selected">false</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
```

But the combo box has only one value.

Please let me know if there is any help for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With `th:if` you add a node only if the condition is true. So it's clear that only one option can be added.

`th:selected` should be your friend